# Dynamically created Linear Layout does not wrap content

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I am trying to dynamically add textviews inside a `LinearLayout`. once all the width of all the textviews is bigger than the width of the screen I need to create another `LinearLayout` below the first one and continue adding textviews. I am basically splitting a `String` into multiple textviews, because I need to check if some of the words have a **'#'** in front. If so I need to change the color. The problem I am having is that the first `LinearLayout` is very tall (Height does not wrap content). Any help?

LinC is is the linearLayout counter. It get incremented once the widths of the textviews is greater than the screen

```
        public void TextMod()
{
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams,layoutParams2;
    layoutParams= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutParams= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    llay= new LinearLayout(this.c);
    llay.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    llay.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    llay2= new LinearLayout(this.c);
    llay2.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    llay2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    Boolean addl =true;
        String parts[]= this.Dis.split(" ");
        size=parts.length;
        int i=0;
        while( i<size)
        {
            //
            if(textview_wid < this.w )
            {
                TextView valueTV = new  TextView(c);
                String d= parts[i] + " ";
                valueTV.setText(d);
                valueTV.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);      
                 textview_wid +=valueTV.getMeasuredWidth();
                 Log.d(" des", " TEEXT WIDTH " +  valueTV.getMeasuredWidth());
                if(d.charAt(0)=='#') 
                {
                    valueTV.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
                }
                if(addl)
                {
                     if(LinC==0)
                     {
                        llay.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        this.Lin.addView(llay);
                     }
                     if(LinC==1)
                     {
                        llay2.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                        this.Lin.addView(llay2);
                     }



                    addl=false;

                }

                 valueTV.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                if(LinC==0)llay.addView(valueTV);
                if(LinC==1)llay2.addView(valueTV);
                i++;
            }
            else
            {

                Log.d(" des", " TOTAL TEXTVIE WIDE " + textview_wid);
                textview_wid =0;
                LinC++;
                addl=true;

            }


         //   valueTV.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);




        }

}
```

OnCreate

```
            @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

     height =metrics.heightPixels;
     width=metrics.widthPixels;
    L=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll);

    //layoutParams= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    sep = new DescriptionStringSep(s,L,this,width);
    sep.TextMod();


}
```

XML

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >



<LinearLayout 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:orientation="vertical"

    >



</LinearLayout>

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you paste the rest of your code? onCreate()?

Comment: @AndyFaizan ok i have posted it

Comment: please post the xml file (layout)

Comment: @AM om i have posted it

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing wrong

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

This sets the content view to the xml layout passed as a parameter. Since you're creating a dynamic layout in the `TextMod` method,  call it later on in your code and set the resultant layout in your activity. You should do this

```
onCreate(){
    ...
    LinearLayout mLayout;
    mLayout = sep.TextMod(); // make TextMod return the root view
    setContentView(mLayout);
}
```

Comment: could this still be used if the TextMod function is to be used in listviews?

Comment: the textmod function is adding the two linear layouts to a linear layout in the main xml

Comment: Yes you can use it in a listview but you need paste code related to that if you face problems. If you're adding two layouts into a layout in the main.xml, refer the main layout in your xml and set the dynamic layouts as children.

Comment: i havent tried it. I was trying out stuff. I changed the if(textview_wid < this.w) line to (textview_wid < this.w -100) and it works how i want it to work, on the Nexus 5

Comment: Do you mean 100dp when you say 100?